# Problem with Lightning-button LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-button

Hello guys I have being working on a LWC custom form that has a lightning-button that do some action. I have notice that what I am in the same row of the button but outside this button and I make some click that action performs. The next picture where I doddled explains what part I am refer to. I only want to run the action only when the user clicks exactly in that button not outside this.

[image]

My html is this one:

```
<template if:true={seccionDocumentosFirmar}>
    <br>
    <br>
        <div class="containerTitle">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="action:new_note" alternative-text="New note" title="New note"></lightning-icon>
            <div class="slds-text-heading_large margin">Documentos a firmar.</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open  active-section-name={activeSections}>
            <lightning-accordion-section name="Mensaje" label="Escriba el mensaje">
                <lightning-input-rich-text onchange={handleMensaje} placeholder="Mensaje a enviar..." required="true"
                formats={formats}></lightning-input-rich-text>
            </lightning-accordion-section>
            <lightning-accordion-section name="SeleccionDocumentos" label="Seleccione los documentos">
                <br>
                <br>
                <template if:true={showSpinner}>
                    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium" class="spinnerClass"></lightning-spinner>
                </template>
    
                <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">Cargar documentos</div> <br />
                <lightning-input type="file" label="Attachment" onchange={handleFileUploaded} multiple>
                </lightning-input>
                <template if:true={filesData}>
                    <template for:each={filesData} for:item="imgName" for:index="index">
                        <span key={imgName.fileName} data-id={index} onclick={removeReceiptImage}
                            class="removeImage">x</span> &nbsp;
                        {imgName.fileName}
                        <br key={imgName.fileName}>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <br />
                <br>
                <br>
            </lightning-accordion-section>
            <lightning-accordion-section name="SeleccionMiembros" label="Seleccione los miembros">
                <lightning-combobox label="Comunidad energética" placeholder="Seleccione la communidad energética..." required
                options={nombresComunidadesEnergeticas}
                onchange={handleSeleccionComunidadEnergetica} ></lightning-combobox>
                <template if:true={dataForDataTable}>
                    <template if:true={records}>
                        <!--LIGHTNING SEARCH-->
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                            <div class="slds-col ">
                                <lightning-input type="text" label="Miembro" placeholder="Introduzca el miembro a buscar..."
                                    onchange={handleSearchChange}></lightning-input><br /><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col">
        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--LIGHTNING DATATABLE-->
                        <div
                            class=" slds-text-align_center  slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_left slds-border_bottom">
                            <lightning-datatable class="table" key-field="idMiembroComunidad" data={recordsToDisplay} onrowselection={handleSelectedMembers}
                         columns={columns}></lightning-datatable>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-spread"
                            style="padding-top: 0.5em;">
                            <!--RECORDS PER PAGE-->
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <div class="slds-list_inline slds-p-bottom_xx-small">
                                    <label class="slds-text-color_weak slds-p-horizontal_x-small" for="recordsPerPage">Page
                                        Size:</label>
                                    <div class="slds-select_container">
                                        <select class="slds-select" id="recordsPerPage" onchange={handleRecordsPerPage}>
                                            <template for:each={pageSizeOptions} for:item="option">
                                                <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>
                                            </template>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--PAGE NAVIGATION-->
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">
                                <lightning-button disabled={bDisableFirst} icon-name="utility:jump_to_left" label="First"
                                    class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small" alternative-text="first page"
                                    onclick={firstPage}></lightning-button>
                                <lightning-button disabled={bDisableFirst} icon-name="utility:chevronleft" label="Previous"
                                    alternative-text="Previous" onclick={previousPage}></lightning-button>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span class="slds-badge">Showing {pageNumber} &nbsp;of&nbsp; {totalPages}
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Page(s)</span>
                                &nbsp;
                                <lightning-button disabled={bDisableLast} icon-name="utility:chevronright" label="Next"
                                    alternative-text="Next" onclick={nextPage} class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small"
                                    icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
                                <lightning-button disabled={bDisableLast} icon-name="utility:jump_to_right" label="Last"
                                    alternative-text="last page" onclick={lastPage} icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
                            </div>
                            <!--TOTAL RECORDS-->
                            <div class="slds-clearfix">
                                <div class="slds-float_right">
                                    <span class="slds-badge"> Total Records: {totalRecords}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <br>
                <br>
            </lightning-accordion-section>
        </lightning-accordion>
        <div class="slds-clearfix">
             <lightning-button class="slds-align_absolute-center" label="Enviar información" variant="brand" onclick={handleEnviarInformacion}></lightning-button>

        </div>
</template>
```

Could someone tell me how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can you please [edit] the question to include the template for the component in which this `lightning-button` is used?

Comment: @PhilW There you have